# React, change state from child (callback)

Tags: asp.net, c, reactjs

I want change state in my parent controller when I responde data in child form. But I only catch error: this.setState is not a function. I think I assign this variable somehow to state but I don't know how.

Unless someone has a different idea for this feature. I would like this form to disappear after clicking send in child component.

Someone will help?

Parent:

```
class Folder extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
 super(props)
 this.state = {
   add: false
 };
}

onAdd(){
 this.setState({add : false});
 }

 render() {
   return (
    <div className={styles.folder} >
       ...
        {this.state.add ? <AddForm callback = {this.onAdd}/> : ""}
    </div>
);
}
```

Child:

```
class AddForm extends React.Component{
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
   this.state = {checked : false};
 }

async add(){
  await POST("https://localhost:5001/Elements/Add", Element.element);
  
  if(Responde.data === true){
  }
  this.props.callback();
}


render() {
    return (
        <div className={styles.add_form}>
          
          <button className={styles.add_form_btn} onClick={this.add.bind(this)}>Add</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becasue you don't `bind(this)` in the parent component. You just add `this.onAdd = this.onAdd.bind(this)` inside the constructor of parent component:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      add: false,
    };
    this.onAdd = this.onAdd.bind(this)
  }
```

Comment: THX. all in all, I think I forgot